# Why my Stroke to Path isn't like in the old tutorial?

Tags: inkscape, stroke

It's my first time in this forum chat, so I'm sorry if there are my words that inappropriate to you all. I use Windows 8.1, Inkscape version 1.2. I have followed an old tutorial, which version is 0.48.

I know it sounds weird why I follow old tutorial not the version like I have now, but I don't see any tutorial on YouTube (Full list) that specific for Inkscape 1.2.

Anyway there is a problem when I follow this tutorial, I have tried on my object, *Stroke to Path* > *Path(Break Apart)*> *Path(Union)*. The result is here:

[image]

But, in the old tutorial after I follow the same steps, the result is different, like this:

[image]

I don't know if it's because of the difference of version that being used or something else. Why can this happen?

Here's the file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1EPYHwC_6yMHmWL-dzv1JP7HLamOnOqk6/view?usp=sharing.

Comment: It's different because Inkscape has changed considerably since version 0.48. Try to look for newer tutorials if you can.  There's a youtube channel called Logos by Nick, where there are newer tutorials for Inkscape 1.2. When used on a text object, Stroke to Path now results in two nested groups. Look at the Layers and Objects panel, you can see them in your screen shot. Just ungroup twice to remove the groups before doing the Break Apart or any boolean operations.

Comment: @BillyKerr   Wow it worked.. i have no idea i must ungroup twice, cause i think once is enough. About tutorial part, actually this tutorial that i have problem with is from Logo By Nick tutorials.

Comment: Give Nick some time, he will likely post more new tutorials using Inkscape 1.2.x. The new version of Inkscape is fairly recent.  If you come across similar problems like this in future, always check the Object and Layers panel to see the construction. It can help you find out if there are extra groups you might not be aware of.

Comment: Yeah... I will always check up the panel to be extra careful .... anyway thanks for your help